# router.js file NOT created when installing vue-router

Tags: vue.js

I am following this guide:

https://github.com/bradtraversy/vue_crash_todolist

https://youtu.be/Wy9q22isx3U

At the end its shown how to install the `vue-router` through `vue ui`. I have done that as well:

[image]

but for some reason I don't get a `router.js` file as the author describes in the video.

Is something wrong with my installation or has the creating of a `router.js` file been removed in later versions of vue??

I am on:

```
Now using node v10.0.0 (npm v5.6.0)
@vue/cli-service-global@4.2.2
@vue/cli 4.2.2
```

Comment: You should check that the author uses the same versions of the dependencies that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should definitely be there after installation through the vue ui

[Try updating to the latest version of node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

As u123 mentioned, in the most recent version of vue cli, the router is added to **src/router/index.js**

Comment: Hm I have a suspicion that it’s no longer called route.js but instead index.js most of the content seems to be added to index.js